# Calling a controller extension method from a view

Tags: model-view-controller, methods

I created some extension method for controller class and I can call them from derived controllers (such as home controller). But it seems that I cannot call them from view.
is there any way to call an extension method of controller in a view?

Comment: Did you include the namespace of the extension method in the view?

Comment: yes I did. I can access the method but when I use it as the target for an actionlink, it is not called.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to call an extension method as a controller action. You can't do that.

What you need to do instead is create an action that calls the extension method. Here's a short example:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    this.ExtensionMethod();
    return View();
}

public static void ExtensionMethod(this Controller controller)
{
    ...
}
```

So when you want to call it as a parameter to an `actionlink`, you can use `Foo`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Foo");
```

Comment: Thanks. My extension method returns ActionResult and also get the same type of parameter that my controller action is getting, so I am not able to do this as then I have two method with the same signature, one extension method and the other controller action. The idea is that I have some library that when included to a project, it give some functionality to view/controller without the need of developer interaction (similar to a control in asp.net which you drop it in your page and it resides in a dll). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Ah I think I understand. That's a complicated scenario. My first thought would be to see if you really need that design. Changing it to what I have above is the correct way of doing this. My second thought then would be... you'd have to look deep into the MVC code and customize it to find and call your extension method.